# Automatically launch apps using adb

Tags: android-intent, adb, android-logcat, monkeyrunner

I am trying to do some fuzz testing against an Android apk, and I need to launch the apps from adb, input some string value, click submit, and click OK for any pop up.

I don't have much knowledge about Android, and I just managed to launch it from adb. My next step is to do the steps on the phone manually and log down the activity using logcat, and hopefully automate this using adb command.

I still need lots of research to implement this, but is this the right direction? Or is this feasible with adb at all?

I know there are few apps which help to record user actions and replay, but root is required, so I can't proceed with that.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Regards,
sqr

===== 12/7 11:07pm =====
I did a bit further research, and it seems that monkeyrunner maybe the right tools to automate the user input and suppression of pop ups. Yet to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which features [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) a user friendly GUI, which is a really powerful tool for generating ready-to-execute scripts and testcases for automating Black box testing.
You just do whatever you want on the device representation (a window much like emulator) and the actions and tests are recorded and can be executed later.

This does not require root.

Comment: Hi Diego, this works for my purpose and  it is very easy to use!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you have any questions you can use the tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidviewclient